# $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{v=0}^{\infty } \frac{ (a+b x)^k (a-b x)^v}{(k!)^2 v!}U(v+1,k+v+2,x)$ with $U$ being confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am wondering if I can convert the expression

$$f(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{v=0}^{\infty } \frac{ (a+b x)^k (a-b x)^v}{(k!)^2 v!}U(v+1,k+v+2,x)\\{\rm with}\,\,x,a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},b\in\mathbb{R},\tag{1}$$

where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function, to a simpler equation. Eq.(1) is quite complicate to calculate. Possible simplifications are a reduction to a single sum or completely remove the sums, simplification of the fraction, or replacement of the hypergeometric function.

Comment: Where is this sum from and what have you tried? Rewriting the confluent U function in terms of $\,_1\text F_1$ will help break up the sum into 2 new terms to work. Finally, the inner sum can be turned into a [double hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) and maybe simplified from there.